# Windows não mostra arquivos recém inseridos em um diretório de um real device android /sdcard/Download/

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Tenho uma aplicação Android que eu importo um arquivo SQLite para dentro do aplicativo para realizar as consultas e alterações. Quando termino de manipular eu exporto esse mesmo arquivo para uma pasta acessível ao usuário para que possa pegar o mesmo arquivo e usá-lo.

VERSÃO DO ANDROID: 4.4.4

Tenho essa função para importar o arquivo

```
 public void ImportarDB()
 {
    try
    {
        string script1 = "cp /sdcard/Download/file.db /data/data/br.com.app.inventario/file.db";
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(script1);
         script1 = "rm /sdcard/Download/file.db";
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(script1);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
 }
```

E essa para exportar

```
 public void ExportarDB()
 {

    try
    {
        string script1 = "cp /data/data/br.com.app.inventario/file.db  /sdcard/Download/file.db";
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(script1);                                         
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                   
    }
 }
```

Após executar a função "ExportarDB" meu diretório fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no meu dispositivo Android consultando pela linha de comando do ADB o diretório consta assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas imagens são referentes ao mesmo diretório, gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar meu diretório no Windows assim que inserir um novo arquivo.

Obs: Não é viavel reiniciar o aparelho ou a máquina. Já tentei desplugar o usb e plugar novamente; já tentei esses 2 trechos de código mas não funcionam:

`SendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaMounted, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + "/sdcard/Download/")));`  `Android.Media.MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(this, new string[] { "/sdcard/Download/" }, null, null );`

Comment: Tente usar um gerenciador de arquivos no próprio dispositivo. O Windows é conhecido por apresentar esse tipo de problema ao gerenciar arquivos de um dispositivo móvel. Já passei por esse problema. Eu uso o File Manager HD Free.

Comment: Me avise se funcionar, que eu coloco como resposta para a pergunta :)

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou bem, seria como uma solução alternativa. Gostaria de implementar esse método do gerenciador de arquivos na minha aplicação para não precisar abrir outro aplicativo, tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Sim. Existem métodos que mostram quais arquivos existem dentro de uma determinada pasta, como por exemplo Directory.GetFiles(folderPath). Dessa maneira você consegue listar os arquivos presentes dentro de determinada pasta e depois criar botões, se desejar, para excluir, renomear tais arquivos.